# Different execution with valgrind (or O0)

Tags: c++, valgrind

For a large project, I get different execution log if I use O3 as opposed to O0. The one with O3 is faulty, and triggers an assertion.

If I use valgrind (with either O0 or O3), I get the correct behaviour.

My feeling is that there is some uninitialized variable, but shouldn't valgrind detect that?

I also get correct behaviour if I compile in Windows with mingw! So, the only "incorrect" behaviour is with O3 flag in Unix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another thing you could try is asan (the address sanitizer).

Comment: "and triggers an assertion" - is there something secret about that assertion or are you willing to share it and the stack trace that got you there, *verbatim*, and *in your question please*?

Comment: Could you show an error and the line where it happens? Sometimes optimizer may flush out UB that's not visible otherwise, for example, because the timing changes.

Comment: The particular assertion won't help as it is purely logical (related to the algorithm that is running). The log will not help much either as it is more than 300 thousand lines long. The first diff between the 'presumably' correct log and the one that ends in assertion appears after 258 thousand lines, and I am trying to figure out the difference atm.

Comment: I'm afraid if those pieces of information won't help much then we're likely not going to be able to help much either. It is difficult to troubleshoot a problem without seeing it.

Comment: No worries, I'll keep debugging it.

Comment: Are you using the strictest compiler warning flags? -Wall -Wextra maybe even -pedantic

Comment: Just tried using the flags, didn't help. Thanks.